# How do I create a dynamic key to be added to a JavaScript object in forEach loop using spread operator

Tags: javascript

```
var arr= [{name:'xyz'},{name:'abc'}];

arr.forEach(function(a){
    a.age = 25;
    a.country = 'USA'
    a.technology = 'JavaScript'
});
```

How can I add these dynamic key-value pair with spread operator using ES6 syntax

Comment: Why do you want to use [spread _syntax_](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) (_"Spread syntax allows an iterable such as an array expression or string to be expanded in places where zero or more arguments (for function calls) or elements (for array literals) are expected, or an object expression to be expanded in places where zero or more key-value pairs (for object literals) are expected."_)?

Comment: why spread operator?

Answer (score 2):

```
 arr = arr.map(prev => ({ ...prev, age: 25, country:"USA" }));
```

Comment: Hi, I want this with forEach loop

Comment: `map` is a foreach loop

Comment: @Sheena: No you don't.

Comment: @Luis felipe De jesus Munoz:

I want to use forEach because I don't want to return a new array , I want to update the array – Sheena 8 mins ago

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can use spread syntax to modify an object, only to create a new object. If you want something that allows you to use a Javascript object literal to modify, use `Object.assign()`

```
arr.forEach(a => Object.assign(a, {
    age: 25,
    country: 'USA',
    technology: 'Javascript'
}));
```

Comment: @GerardoFurtado SO desperately needs a paren-matcher :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this code:

```
var arr= [{name:'xyz'},{name:'abc'}];

var obj =  {
    age: 25,
    country: 'USA',
    technology: 'JavaScript'
};

arr.forEach(function(a){
    Object.assign(a, obj);
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.